# Не могу подключиться к вебсокету с реального ip

Tags: apache, websocket, ratchet

Я использую php вебсокеты (ratchet библиотека), подключаюсь к ним через js.
Всё отлично работает без сервера, если в сокетах ставить прослушку на localhost `new Ratchet\App("localhost", 8080, '0.0.0.0', $loop);` и подключаться к нему соответственно в js `new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/chat");`
С сервером (apache) на локальном адресе тоже всё работает, для этого достаточно в php и в js вместо localhost указать 192.168.1.63 (адрес моего хоста в локальной сети), и на сайт я попадаю и к вебсокетам подключаюсь.
Однако если вместо локального адреса указать реальный ip, то на сервер я попадаю, но к вебсокетам меня не подключает. Хром выдаёт 404 ошибку с таким сообщением:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://90.188.139.20:8080/chat' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Сервер покачто у меня включен, можете подключиться к нему по адресу http://90.188.139.20/index2.html

Answer (score 0):

Судя по тому что ваш айпи пингуется, но вебсервер уже не отвечает - вы скорее всего сидите за NAT. А для этого надо:

1. Пробросить в роутере порт 8080 на ваш сервер
2. На сервере в PHP при создании вебсокет сервера указывать айпи из локалки 192.168.1.63

Comment: 8080 порт открыт и на свой сервер я попасть могу, не подключается только к вебсокету. Попробовал в сокетах указывать 192.168.1.63 адрес, но всёравно 404 ошибка.

Comment: Я уже в другом месте более подробно описал мои недельные мучения по этому вопросу: https://toster.ru/q/387091 Там можно подробнее с проблемой ознакомиться.

Comment: Ответ остается все равно тем же самым. проверяйте роутер и проброс порта. Его открытость значит мало. может у вас он не туда куда-то идет. Покажите хоть конфиги все роутера и остального, а-то гадаем на кофейной гуще.